# invalid syntax non specific error

Tags: python, syntax

```
def rotate():
listparam = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 5, 6]]
listlength = len(listparam)
elementlength = len(listparam[0])
print(listlength)
print(elementlength)
i = 0
j = 0
for i in range(elementlength):
    row[i] = []
    for j in range(listlength):
        row[i].append(listparam[i][j]
```

I get an invalid syntax error on a blank line
Here's a pic of what im seeing.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jj3f.png

Comment: please tag the language you are using.

Comment: Syntax depends on language. at least add a language tag. Also, if this is python, make sure that indentation is correct: It's syntactically relevant!

Comment: `row[i].append(listparam[i][j]` is missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: You seem to have a bad editor/IDE: a decent editor would show the full Python traceback, and have a pointer to the exact point of the SyntaxError. What are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
    row[i].append(listparam[i][j]
```

You're missing a parenthesis on the last line.

```
    row[i].append(listparam[i][j])
```